# Unable to turn on GWT Super Dev Mode

Tags: gwt

While trying to use GWT Super Dev Mode, I followed those guidelines :

- [GWT-2.5-Super-Dev-Mode](http://www.insideit.fr/post/GWT-2.5-Super-Dev-Mode)
- [Introducing Super Dev Mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode?hl=fr)
- [How does GWT's Super Dev Mode work?](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/how-does-gwts-super-dev-mode-work)

However, I am stuck at the step trying to turn on Super Dev Mode :

Once I fully compiled my project, I run the code server and the dev mode, go at `http://127.0.0.1:8888/myapp.html` (without the `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`) and then click on the bookmark `Dev Mode On`. It detects my module, asks me to recompile, a glass screen appears with a message `Compiling MyApp ...` and then nothing ... No error, no stack trace either in Chrome or Eclipse. Just nothing happens.

Debugging the js code from `dev_mode_on.js` file, the script is interrupted at line 324 :

```
...
function getBindingParameters(module_name, get_prop_map) {
  var session_key = '__gwtDevModeSession:' + module_name;

  --> var prop_map = get_prop_map(); <--
...
```

Once the function `get_prop_map` is called, a few more obfuscated functions run and the debugger returns.

I know it is still experimental, but do you have any idea of what I could have done wrong ?

**PS:** I am using GWT 2.5, GWT-maven-plugin 2.5 and Chrome 23.0.1271.64 m

Comment: can you check the console of your SuperDevMode process in eclipse.
It should say something like that: ```[INFO]    Compiling 1 permutation [INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have found a similar issue and tracked down the cause, looks like a boundary case not handled in GWT.

More info can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7894

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I can give some general debugging tips for this sort of problem.

Super Dev Mode currently (as of 2.5) doesn't report any progress to the web browser while it's compiling. It won't update the dialog until the compile finishes. So it's possible that it's just very slow for your program for some reason, or the compile stopped and somehow didn't report an error like it normally does.

However, there are other ways you can monitor its progress. The compiler log is available as a web page by following links from the code server's front page; you will have to refresh the page to see updates. Or you could look at the log on disk in the code server's work directory. (You can set the work directory with the -workDir argument when you start it.)

Another way is to start the code server from the command line. Any stack traces from the code server will be printed there. You should also be able to look at the output in Eclipse or IntelliJ if you're running it from there.

From this you should be able to tell whether the compiler is slow, but still working (it's still printing output) or has actually stopped with a stack trace.